# Delphi XE2 TIdUDPClient ReceiveString overload does not work

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe2, broadcast, indy10

I am using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2 Update 4 and the Indy package shipped with it.

My intention is to find a server in LAN with broadcast from a TIdUDPClient that waits for a response from the server to get its IP. Receiving the data works fine if I use the TIdUDPClient method ReceiveString with no arguments.

But when I try to use the overloaded version found in the Indy 10 Documentation version 10.5.8.3 coming with RAD Studio, it does not compile and shows *'E2250: There is no overloaded version of 'ReceiveString' that can be called with these arguments'*.
Here is my code:

```
unit Client;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase,
  IdUDPClient, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdGlobal;

type
  TFormLC = class(TForm)
    UDPClient: TIdUDPClient;
    LServer: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  FormLC: TFormLC;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function findServer:string;
var ans, ip : string;
    port: TIdPort;
begin
  with FormLC.UDPClient do begin
    Active := True;
    BroadcastEnabled:=True;
    Broadcast('ServerRequest', 1234);
    ans := ReceiveString(ip, port);
    Active := False;
  end;
  if SameText(ans, 'ServerAccept') then
    result := ip
  else
    result := '';
end;


procedure TFormLC.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ans:string;
begin
  LServer.Caption := findServer;
end;

end.
```

I noticed that the [online documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html) of Indy differs from the documentation that comes with the IDE and tried it as described there, without succes.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the `with` statement, you are passing the `port` property of the `TIdUDPClient` instead of the local variable `port` to the `ReceiveString` method.

```
function findServer:string;
var ans, ip : string;
    port: TIdPort;
begin
  with FormLC.UDPClient do begin
    ....
    ans := ReceiveString(ip, port);//here you are passing the port property 
    Active := False;
  end;
  .... 
end;
```

As workaround rename you `port` local variable like so :

```
 function findServer:string;
var ans, ip : string;
    vport: TIdPort;
begin
  with FormLC.UDPClient do begin
    .... 
    ans := ReceiveString(ip, vport);//now will work
    Active := False;
  end;
end;
```

or even better don't use the `with` statement.

Comment: Definitely get rid of the `with` statement

Answer (score 2):

`TIdUDPClient` has 2 overloads for `ReceiveString()`:

```
function ReceiveString(const AMSec: Integer = IdTimeoutDefault; AByteEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}; ADestEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil{$ENDIF}): string; overload;

function ReceiveString(var VPeerIP: string; var VPeerPort: TIdPort; const AMSec: Integer = IdTimeoutDefault; AByteEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}; ADestEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil{$ENDIF}): string; overload;
```

When you call `ReceiveString()` without parameters, you are calling the first overload.  When trying to call the second overload, your code fails to compile because your `with` statement is passing the `TIdUDPClient.Port` property to the second parameter, instead of your local `port` variable.  The compile will not allow you to pass a property to a `var` parameter.

You need to remove the `with` statement and/or rename your `port` variable to resolve the conflict.